# Issues with detecting a string within a string

Tags: java, string

On a site called Codingbat.com I have been presented with the challenge of detecting whether a string ends in "ly" or not. I have thoroughly checked my code, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I input "ly" it detects perfectly fine, however, words such as "oddly" or "exactly" don't issue the true Boolean response as they should. Here is my code so far:

```
if (str.length() > 1) {
  String lastTwo = str.substring(str.length()-2, str.length());
  if (lastTwo == "ly") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing references, not objects. You need `lastTwo.equals("ly")`.

Comment: Java has a built in method String#endsWith

`String s = "odly";
System.out.println(s.endsWith("ly"));`